# LINQ SQL Select from list using partial match

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a list `wbsList` containing the current elements:

```
SS-B23813
SS-B23814
```

I want the SQL lookup to retreive all wbs elements that starts with those numbers to be listed, so I use this code:

```
var q =
    from a in MESdb.GetTable<t_SAP_Order>()
    where wbsList.Contains(a.WbsElement) 
    orderby a.WbsElement, a.OrderDescription
    select a;
```

This results in nothing, because it only shows exact matches. All my wbs'es has a longer string (`SS-B23813-24-1-15-06-100`)
How can I use the list as a partial search criteria?

**UPDATE:**

When I change the code to Dunth's answer, I get the following error:
Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except Contains operator.

I wonder if this error comes because of some error when I try to display the result in a datagrid:

```
caseGrid.DataSource = q.Select(o => new
                    {
                        Workcenter = o.MainWorkCenter,
                        SO = o.Ordr,
                        Description = o.OrderDescription,
                        SerialNumber = o.SerialNumber,
                        BasicFinish = o.BasicFin
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Are only two strings in the list? In Linq-To-Objects this would work: `MESdb.GetTable<t_SAP_Order>().Where(a => wbsList.Any(s => a.WbsElement.Contains(s)))`. Now `Contains` is a sub-string search.

Comment: No, the list could contain several more items.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to find where it might not be at the start.

```
var q = MESdb.GetTable<t_SAP_Order>()
            .Where(a => wbsList.Any(b => a.WbsElement.Contains(b)))
            .OrderBy(a => a.WbsElement)
            .ThenBy(a => a.OrderDescription).ToList();
```

Comment: StartsWith is not an option, and when I use contains I get this error: MultiTool.t_SAP_Order does not contain a definition for Contains

Comment: When I edit the code to: 'var q = MESdb.GetTable<t_SAP_Order>().Where(a => wbsList.Any(b => a.WbsElement.StartsWith(b)));' I get the following error at runtime: 'Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.'

Comment: sorry, the starts with cant be used with linq to sql and was a mistake in the contains, should have WbsElement after a, will edit it now. It was doing contains on the element rather than the string property. It should also include your order by now.

Comment: so if you debug and look at what q is does that contain the result you expect? If you try contains instead of startswith does that work? I noticed that is the error you had with startswith. OR try my latest edit with the .ToList() on the end. It may be that you have to pull your results into memory before doing your select.

Comment: I get the same error with StartWith/Contains and the latest edit with ToList().

Comment: The only suggestion I have left then would be .ToList after GetTable<...>() but that pulls the whole table in to memory which isn't good.

Answer (score 0):

`Contains` does a sql `IN(...)`, you want a sql `LIKE` so use `wbList.StartsWith(a.WbsElement)`